Calculate sum of self-exponentation
Given an array of positive integers, calculate the sum of each number raised to its own power. For example, given 4,6,7, the code needs to return \$4^4+6^6+7^7=870455\$.
This is code-golf, so shortest code wins.

Welcome to Code Golf Stack Exchange! I downvoted your challenge because I find it to be overly basic and too similar to other challenges on this site, but please don't let that discourage you from trying to make another challenge! For future tasks, we have a Sandbox for Proposed Challenges that you can post your ideas to and receive feedback before getting any solutions.

@noodleperson Thank you for your advice! I will try to follow your suggestions in the future.

Related: Is it a Munchausen Number?

Uiua, 4 bytes
/+ⁿ.

Try it
/+    # Sum of
  ⁿ   # each to the power of
   .  # itself


Vyxal s, 1 byte
e

Try it online.
Explanation:
e   # Vectorized power with itself using the (implicit) input-list twice
 s  # Sum the list
    # (after which the result is output implicitly)


Nibbles, 4 nibbles (2 bytes)
+.$^

Attempt This Online!
+.$^     # full program
+x$^$$   # with implicit variables shown
+        # sum of
 .       # map over
  $      # each element of input
   ^     # x to the power of y:
    $    #   x is each element
    $    #   y is each element


I'm surprised you didn't directly count +.$^ as 1 single byte, since you're already so willing to use sub-byte size units for characters. Heck, why not just make it 4 bits, thus half a byte ???

@RAREKpopManifesto - The +.$^ string is just a (somewhat) human-readable representation of the 4x 4-bit nibbles of the actual code, which consists of 1000, 1100, 0011 and 1110 (8c3e).  These are saved into a 2-byte file, which is executed by the Nibbles interpreter (see screenshot).  The stderr output of the ATO link also indicates the final size of the program in bytes.  If you're interested in Nibbles, check it out here!

Desmos, 14 bytes
f(l)=l^l.total

Try It On Desmos!
Try It On Desmos! - Prettified

Python 3.8 (pre-release),  29  26 bytes
-3 bytes thanks to Albert.Lang.
lambda l:sum(map(pow,l,l))

Try it online!
Explanation
lambda l:                    # Anonymous lambda
         sum(            )   # Sum of...
             map(pow,   )    # Exponentiation of...
                     l,l     # element ** element for each element


Use map and pow for -3:lambda l:sum(map(pow,l,l))

@Albert.Lang: I always thought map could only have 2 arguments...

Whitespace, 115 bytes
[S S S N
_Push_sum=0][N
S S N
_Create_Label_OUTER_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate_sum][S N
S _Duplicate_sum][T N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_Integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][S N
S _Duplicate_input][N
T   S T N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_PRINT][S N
S _Duplicate_input][S N
S _Duplicate_input][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_INNER_LOOP][S S S T   N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract_top_two][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   S S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_RETURN][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S T  S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_input_to_top][T   S S N
_Multiply_top_two][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][N
S N
S N
_Jump_to_INNER_LOOP][N
S S S S N
_Create_Label_RETURN][S N
N
_Discard_top_0][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S N
N
_Discard_top_input][T   S S S _Add_top_two][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_OUTER_LOOP][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_PRINT][S N
N
_Discard_top_0][T   N
S T _Print_as_Integer]

Letters S (space), T (tab), and N (new-line) added as highlighting only.
[..._some_action] added as explanation only.
Since Whitespace can only read input one character/integer at a time, the input must contain a trailing 0 so we'll know when we're done reading inputs.
Try it online (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).
Explanation in pseudo-code:
Integer sum = 0
Start OUTER_LOOP:
  Integer input = Read STDIN as integer
  If (input == 0):
    Stop OUTER_LOOP, and jump to PRINT
  Integer product = input
  Integer count = input
  Start INNER_LOOP:
    count = count - 1
    If (count == 0):
      Stop INNER_LOOP, and jump to RETURN
    product = product * input
    Go to next iteration of INNER_LOOP
  RETURN:
    sum = sum + product
    Go to next iteration of OUTER_LOOP
PRINT:
  Print sum as integer to STDOUT
  (implicitly stop the program with an error: No exit defined)


05AB1E, 2 bytes
mO

Try it online.
Explanation:
m   # Take the power of each value in the (implicit) input-list with each value in
    # the (implicit) input-list at the same position
 O  # Sum those
    # (after which this sum is output implicitly as result)


Julia 1.0, 12 bytes
~x=sum(x.^x)

Try it online!
This solution showcases how operations in Julia can be vectorized with a dot. I've redefined a single-character operator, but an anonymous function x->sum(x.^x) could also be used for the same score.
By the way, sum can accept a subfunction to be called on each element before summation. For example, if A is a vector, sum(sqrt.(x)) can be shortened to sum(sqrt,x). It's not helpful in this case, since there's no unary definition for ^, but this method has been useful for most of my solutions involving sum, often saving bytes over solutions involving count.

I don't think it gets any shorter, but !x=x'x.^.~-x is a fun alternative at the same length

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 8 bytes
Tr[#^#]&

Try it online! Unnamed function taking a list like {4, 6, 7} as input. The exponentiation operator ^ automatically distributes over arrays of the same length, and Tr of a one-dimensional list is its sum.

APL(Dyalog Unicode),  4 bytes SBCS
+.*⍨

Try it on APLgolf!

Factor, 14 bytes
[ dup v^ sum ]

Try it online!

Charcoal, 7 5 bytes
ＩΣＸθθ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code.
   θ    Input array
  Ｘ     Vectorised raised to power
    θ   Input array
 Σ      Take the sum
Ｉ       Cast to string
        Implicitly print

Edit: Saved 2 bytes because I forgot that Power is one of the four (five on ATO) operators that auto-vectorises if both parameters are lists.
7 bytes to take input as a string:
ＩΣＥＡＸιι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Power auto-casts strings to integer, so I don't need to write Ｉι twice.

Arturo, 19 bytes
$=>[∑map&'x->x^x]

Try it!
Explanation
$=>[]      ; a function where input is assigned to &
∑          ; sum of...
map&'x->   ; map over input and assign current elt to x
x^x        ; x to the x power


JavaScript (V8), 28 bytes
x=>x.reduce((a,c)=>a+c**c,0)

Try it online!

Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! You can save quite a few bytes with c**c instead of Math.pow(c,c)

Thanks @emanresuA!

Haskell, 17 bytes
sum.map((^)<*>id)

Try it online!
The (^)<*>id is point-free for \x->x^x. A list-comprehension solution is the same length.
f l=sum[x^x|x<-l]

Try it online!

If imports are allowed, sum.map(join(^)) saves one byte.

Brachylog, 7 bytes
{^↙?}ᵐ+

Try it online!
Rare use of ↙. There is a less elegant version also for 7 bytes: gjz^₎ᵐ+
Explanation
{   }ᵐ     Map for each integer:
 ^           Raise to the power...
  ↙?         ...of itself
      +    Sum


min, 23 bytes
((dup pow ceil)map sum)



Jelly, 3 bytes
*`S

Try it online!
Explanation:
*`S 
*   Raise to        
 `    its own [4,6,7] => [256, 46656, 823543]
  S Sum       [256, 46656, 823543] => 870455


C (gcc), 85 + 3 bytes (-lm)
main(c,v,j,t,i)char**v;{i=t=0;while(i<c)j=atoi(i++[v]),t+=pow(j,j);printf("%d",t-1);}

This is about the maximum I can optimize it without using Lambdas, which would probably make the code even longer without manual Assembly rewriting.
I wanted to use something different than printf(), but since itoa() for some reason isn't available, I couldn't swap it with puts() because it didn't support string formatting.
Try it online!

73 bytes; FYI, you may answer questions with a function instead of a full program, which allows you to omit I/O, Doing so for this question allows us to pack everything in 50 bytes.

Thanks! I didn't realize that.

62 bytes for full program version by using scanf instead of atoi+argv

Building on @Mukundan314 49 bytes

Japt -mx, 2 bytes
pU

Try it
       :Implicit map of each U in the input array
pU     :Raise U to the power of U
       :Implicit output of sum of resulting array


Could you include an explanation of your code?

@AndyLiu -m runs the program on each argument and collects the results; -x returns the sum of the program's output. pU implicitly does UpU which says raise U to the power of U.

Thanks for the explanation. I don’t use Japt

Forth (gforth),  103  100 bytes
-3 bytes thanks to ovs
: ^ 1 TUCK +DO OVER * LOOP * ; : s 0 SWAP DUP @ 0 DO DUP I 1+ CELLS + @ DUP ^ ROT + SWAP LOOP DROP ;

Try it online!
No exponentiation in Forth so I first define ^ word and then the s word to compute the sum.
The idea:
addrTab
0 addrTab
\ enter the loop
0 addrTab addrElt1
0 addrTab Elt1
0 addrTab Elt1 Elt1
0 addrTab Elt1^Elt1
addTab 0+Elt1^Elt1
0+Elt1^Elt1 addrTab
... 
0+Elt1^Elt1+...+EltN^EltN addrTab
\ exit the loop
0+Elt1^Elt1+...+EltN^EltN


the exponentiation can be a bit shorter by running the loop for one fewer iteration: : ^ 1 TUCK +DO OVER * LOOP * ;

@ovs great! I think +DO can be replaced by DO, no?

DO would break for input 1, 1 1 DO LOOP is an infinite loop.

J, 5 bytes
1#.^~

Attempt This Online!
^~, called with one argument, raises that argument to the power of itself. When that argument is an array the operation is applied to each cell.
1#. means "from base-1." As it turns out, interpreting a list of integers as the digits of a base-1 number is equivalent to summing them.
This is because #. in J doesn't care whether the digits it is given are greater than the base itself - it just treats them as any other digit, multiplying them by their place value, and summing the results. In this "base-1", the place value is always 1, so this is equivalent to just summing the array.
Thanks to Conor for showing me this trick, saving a byte over the more trivial +/@: I had earlier.

You can use the sum-as-base-1 trick to save 1 byte here: 1#.^~, link

Oh that's interesting, I've never seen that one before. I'm surprised it doesn't error out when the digits are greater than the base, but I guess this makes sense. Thanks for the tip!

J-uby, 9 bytes
:sum+~:**

Attempt This Online!
Expansion of J-uby code to standard Ruby:
:sum + ~:**                        # with spaces
->(a) {:sum.(a, &~:**)}            # (F + G).(*args) == F.(*args, &G)
->(a) {:sum.(a, {|x| (~:**).(x)})} # definition of &
->(a) {:sum.(a, {|x| :**.(x, x)})} # (~F).(x) == F.(x,x)
->(a) {a.sum {|x| x ** x}}         # :F.(x, y) == x.F(y)


Google Sheets, 27 bytes
=sort(sum(if(A:A,A:A^A:A)))

Uses sort as an array enabler, and if() to weed out blanks. In Google Sheets, the numeric value of a blank is zero, and the self-exponents of a blank column would thus sum up to the number of rows in the column.


sed 4.2.2 -rz, 167 137 bytes
s!.*!sed -r 'h;G;:r;s/.\\n./\\n/;x;s/\\n.*//;t;:b;s/.*/\&\\n\&/m;:;t;x;s/^#//;x;tb;G;h;s/\\n(.)/\\1/g;T;s/\\n../\&/;tr'<<<'&'!e
s/\n..//g

Try it online!
This essentially calls a second instance of sed with a snipit of the script I used for this question to calculate the powers, and then concats everything together at the end.

Retina, 30 bytes
~["L$`^¶$.("|""L$`.+
*$($&$*)_

Try it online! Explanation:
L$`.+

Loop over each input integer.
*$($&$*)_

Write that integer followed by a *, repeated (implicitly) that many times, then finally followed by a _. For example, 3 becomes 3*3*3*_, which is how you would calculate 3*3*3 in Retina.
|""

Join the calculations together, implicitly summing them.
["L$`^¶$.("

Turn the calculation into a command that replaces the input with the result of the calculation converted to decimal. (Retina 1 is clever enough not to actually do the calculation in unary if it knows that it will be converting the result to decimal.)
~`
Evaluate the resulting calculation.
For example, for inputs of 4, 6 and 7, the resulting calculation looks like this:
L$`^
$.(4*4*4*4*_6*6*6*6*6*6*_7*7*7*7*7*7*7*_

(The K command doesn't perform calculations so L$`^ is the easiest way.)

Octave, 13 bytes
Simple anonymous function that raises an array to the power of itself on an element wise basis, then sums.
@(x)sum(x.^x)

Try it online!

Excel, 13 Bytes
Takes input as a dynamic array from A1# and output to the calling cell.
=SUM(A1#^A1#)

For the input of ={4;6;7}, outputs 870455.

Bash, 29 bytes
for i;{
let t+=i**i
}
echo $t

use as a function or bash script. takes the array as an arbitrary number of arguments, outputs to stdout.
Attempt This Online!
explanation:
for i;{ # in bash, if the 'in array' part is not provided to 'for elem in array', it implicitly loops over all arguments
let t+=i**i # bash variables are initialized to 0, the rest is simple enough
}
echo $t


Pyth, 3 bytes
s^V

Attempt This Online!
s^V­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
s    # ‎⁡sum of
 ^V  # ‎⁢vectorized power with itself using the (implicit) input-list twice


Created with the help of Luminespire.

Cognate, 24 bytes
(For X(+ ^ Twin)0 Let X)

Attempt This Online!

PowerShell Core, 33 bytes
-join($args|%{'+1'
"*$_"*$_})|iex

Try it online!
Builds the expression as a string, e.g.
+1*4*4*4*4+1*6*6*6*6*6*6+1*7*7*7*7*7*7*7

Then evaluate it

Pyt, 2 bytes
ṖƩ

Try it online!
Ṗ              implicit input; raise each element to itself
 Ʃ             sum the array; implicit print


Java, 32 bytes
l->l.map(x->Math.pow(x,x)).sum()

Try it online!
Saved 17 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen.

When a challenge asks for number or list inputs, inputting as doubles and streams is allowed by default. So if you take a DoubleStream as input, it can be just 32 bytes: l->l.map(x->Math.pow(x,x)).sum() - Try it online.

@KevinCruijssen Good point.

APL+WIN, 7 bytes
Prompts for vector of numbers.
+/i*i←⎕

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

JavaScript (Node.js), 26 bytes
x=>x.map(t=>n+=t**t,n=0)|n

Try it online!

TI-Basic, 4 bytes
sum(Ans^Ans

Takes input in Ans.

Red, 41 bytes
func[b][x: 0 foreach n b[x: n ** n + x]x]

Try it online!

R, 12 bytes
\(x)sum(x^x)

Attempt This Online!

excel, 34 bytes
=LET(a,TEXTSPLIT(A1,","),SUM(a^a))
if there's an array of integers in cell A1 separated by commas (without any zeroes), this should work i think.

Excel, 24 bytes
Input in A:A entered in A1 as an array (i.e. ={4;6;7})
=SUM((A1#^A1#)*(0<>A1#))


Hmm... I think that in past Excel answers that use A1# type references the length of the formula that produces the input has been included in the byte count?

have they? Sadly Excel doesn't allow open references A:A so I can't think of a better way to take the input with variable length.

AWK, -vRS="," 27 14 bytes
{x+=$0^$0}$0=x

This will print the running total for each number. TIO doesn't do it quite right, however.
Try it online!
{for(;i++<NF;)x+=$i^$i}$0=x


ARBLE, 10 bytes
sum(l|x^x)

Try it online!

Clojure, 34 bytes
#(apply +(for[i %](Math/pow i i)))

The input must be a list.

Perl 5 -pa, 18 bytes
map$\+=$_**$_,@F}{

Try it online!

gnuplot 5.0, 40 bytes
f(a)=sum[j=1:words(a)](n=word(a,j),n**n)

Try it online!
There are neither arrays nor vectorized functions in gnuplot 5.0. Instead of an array a common workaround is to use a string with separators.
Funny enough, there is a sum function which is supposed to sum up a range, but it could also be used as an accumulator.

F# (.NET Core), 44 bytes
let s n=n|>Seq.map(fun n->pown n n)|>Seq.sum

Try it online!
Shorter than a Seq.mapFold. Explanation: As many other solutions, this takes a sequence as input, maps each entry to its self-exponent then sums over itself. In F#, the ** operator is limited to floats, so pown is required.
